# ngAnimate with dynamic class 1.2rc1

Tags: angularjs

The new ngAnimate works with a hard coded class:

```
<div ng-view class="forward"></div>

.forward.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: from_right 10s ease;
}
```

but not a dynamic class:

```
<div ng-view ng-class="{'forward': true}"></div>
```

How can I dynamically switch between animations for enter and exit (e.g. forward and back in a phone wizard)?

Answer (score 0):

I literally spent five hours trying to figure out this exact same issue, since I'm trying to do the exact same thing. Turns out, it was a bug in rc1. [Here's the pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/40c0220c47c620070b30aec6ec4552c68a8689eb), which is now in rc2.

Basically, ngAnimate was running before the class could be interpreted, but now it's fixed. Your example should work now:

```
<div ng-view ng-class="{ 'foo': bar }"></div>
```

Alternatively, you could just use the regular class attribute, and bind it to a certain string in the models of your different controllers (if you have separate controllers for each view, e.g. when routing), like so:

```
<div ng-view class="foo"></div>
```

Then, in your javascript, do something like:

```
angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/one', { templateUrl: '/one.html', controller: 'viewOneCtrl' })
        .when('/two', { templateUrl: '/two.html', controller: 'viewTwoCtrl' });
}]);

app.controller('viewOneCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'view-one';
}]);

app.controller('viewTwoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'view-two';
}]);
```